# How much can I reduce the filesize by only importing useful functions in combination with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, filesize, pyinstaller

When I create an .exe with PyInstaller, the exe is roughly 160 MB. This includes all the import from my python script (e.g., numpy, pandas, sys). How much can the filesize be reduced if I only include the functions that I need?

For example:

```
from numpy import cumsum, ravel, diff, append
```

vs

```
import numpy as np
```

Will this be worth the effort to completely re-evaluate my script(s)?

Comment: No. The code for all the functions would still be there, even if you don't use them.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini wait, what? Do you mean that if I do `from numpy import ravel`, that all other modules are into the .exe? That is not how it works for 'normal' python scripts, right?

Comment: Are you distributing numpy inside your installer? Or is it an external dependency?

Comment: It is all inside the executable. It is not an installer, it's a plain .exe. So it is all in there

Comment: Well, then yes: if you include numpy as part of your executable, then the whole numpy code is there.

Comment: Hmm, sounds logical. "from numpy", so it should be there in the first place. Thanks

Comment: What I meant is that there's no difference between `import ...` and `from ... import ...`. PyInstaller will never look at your code, it will just pack it into an executable

Comment: What was your effort on solving your question?

Comment: @kotletschabowy I replaced every numpy command with what I had in my script, but I forgot to make an exact note of the executable filesize. I could have put it all back, with the possibility of breaking stuff, but I thought that this was a SO-worthy question. And now I know for certain, and it makes sense, after all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The code for all the functions would still be there, even if you don't use them. If you include numpy as part of your executable, then the whole numpy code is there, because PyInstaller will never look at your code, it will just pack everything into a single executable file.